# I have extracted source file (Java+xml) from Android app how to edit them in Android studio?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have extracted java and xml files from the apk. I want to edit them.Please tell me how to open them in Android Studio 2.3

Comment: With what purpose ?

Comment: I created an app but i deleted android studio and i have the apk file with source files.But i am not able to open it again in android studio.

Comment: Doesn't matter you deleted Android Studio. The project files are elsewhere.

Comment: If dont wanna help its fine @J